# Opening emacs without the scratch buffer when opening a file (Please tell me what is wrong with my init file snippet)?

Tags: init-file, org-roam, scratch-buffer

I recently updated my `org-roam` package to version 2.2.2 with the following steps:

1. `M-x list-packages`
2. Then select `org-roam` and clicked `delete`.
3. `M-x list-packages` again
4. Then select `org-roam` and clicked `install`.

I think `org-roam` successfully installed (as I can see in my directories the following: `.emacs.d/elpa/org-roam-2.2.2`).

Now if I started Emacs: `**scratch**` buffer dominates everything. Even if I did `emacs /path/to/file/filename` it would open `**scratch**` buffer on top of my file. Now I can `C-x b` to my file, but that was not the default behavior earlier!

I found this related issue on stackoverflow: [Opening emacs without the scratch buffer when opening a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418057/opening-emacs-without-the-scratch-buffer-when-opening-a-file). Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2418129/4949315) to the question I ran `emacs -q /path/to/file/filename` and everything worked as intended.

So upon further investigation I found this as the offending snippet in my `.emacs`:

```
(use-package org-roam
      :ensure t
      :hook
      (after-init . org-roam-mode)
      :custom
      (org-roam-directory "/$HOME/Zettelkasten")
      :bind (:map org-roam-mode-map
              (("C-c n l" . org-roam)
               ("C-c n f" . org-roam-find-file)
               ("C-c n r" . org-roam-graph))
              :map org-mode-map
              (("C-c n i" . org-roam-insert))
              (("C-c n I" . org-roam-insert-immediate))))
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'org-roam-mode)
```

If I comment out the above code, then everything works fine (except obviously `org-roam` doesn't load and I have to manually load it later).

So **questions:**

1. What is wrong with my above code snippet? Why is it causing `**scratch**` to open over my intended file? Earlier `**scratch**` would open but it was not the front buffer. I could always `C-x b` to `**scratch**` if needed.
2. How to fix my code snippet?

**EDIT:**
For now, I am applying the following *aggressive* hot-fix:

```
;; Makes *scratch* empty.
(setq initial-scratch-message "")

;; Removes *scratch* from buffer after the mode has been set.
(defun remove-scratch-buffer ()
  (if (get-buffer "*scratch*")
      (kill-buffer "*scratch*")))
(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook 'remove-scratch-buffer)

;; Removes *messages* from the buffer.
(setq-default message-log-max nil)
(kill-buffer "*Messages*")
```

But I like to keep an instance of `**scratch**` running in the background. So I don't like the above hot-fix at all.

Comment: Why are you adding to `after-init-hook`? Try deleting that bit only and see if that improves matters.

Comment: If I leave `(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'org-roam-mode)` as commented out, and the rest of the above as uncommented, the problem persists. So I don't think it is about the `after-init-hook` part.

Comment: Nevertheless, I think it is wrong to alter `after-init-hook` this way: the buffer that is current at the end of initialization will have `org-roam-mode` run on it - you may have arranged that that buffer is one that *should* be in `org-roam-mode` but that's an error-prone way to do it. Why not depend on `auto-mode-alist`?

Comment: ... and I think you should get rid of the setting in the body of `use-package` as well.

Comment: You do the `after-init-hook` thing *twice*: once in the `use-package` form (the bit after `:hook`) and once at the end.  Have you commented both out?

Comment: @FranBurstall : Yes that fixed it for me. I also commented out `:hook
      (after-init . org-roam-mode)` and it is working fine now.

Comment: @FranBurstall / @NickD: I think I copied that snippet from somewhere (perhaps from system crafter's youtube video on org-roam? not entirely sure from where). Can you please explain what does `auto-mode-alist` do and how to use it?

Comment: Yes I got it from here: https://config.daviwil.com/emacs#org-roam

Comment: Alright I think I understand what was going wrong: [Startup Summary (GNU Emacs)](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Startup-Summary.html) explains at point 18 that "It runs the normal hook after-init-hook." and in point 19 that "If the buffer *scratch* exists and is  ...". So I think the version 2.2.2 of `org-roam` takes longer to load. And so the opening of *scratch* buffer is delayed. So it opens after my file is opened. And so *scratch* offers loads on top of my intended file, as it is opened _after/ later than_ my file. Will that be the correct explanation?

Comment: All: Please provide any relevant comments as answers, if they are answers. Comments can be deleted at any time. Q & A should stand on its own, to help others. Comments are not searchable etc. Thx.

Comment: I tried `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.org\\'" . org-roam-mode))` however I get this error `File mode specification error: (void-function org-roam-mode)`. That is strange: In the above snippet `(after-init . org-roam-mode)` was working. And I have a few other `auto-mode-alist` lines in my config for example: `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.pyx\\'" . python-mode))` or `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.ppl\\'" . python-mode))` and they work fine. What is going wrong now?

Comment: @Drew: Sure - will do if NickD / FranBurstall don't do it first (basically to accept someone else's answer than my own!). Thanks.

Comment: @FranBurstall - feel free to answer. I suspect only a preliminaray answer is possible at this point, about `after-init-hook`. But we can refine it as we learn/understand more.

Comment: Alright the problem maybe even deeper: something _has_ changed in `org-roam` version 2.2.2. Now none of my `org-roam` keybindings work. Further `M-x org-roam` causes the error: `command-execute: Autoloading file /home/geek/.emacs.d/elpa/org-roam-2.2.2/org-roam.elc failed to define function org-roam`.  However I tried to execute `(use-package org-roam
      :ensure t)` in `*scratch*` and it returned `nil`.  I don't know if `nil` is correct or not. I am trying to debug. Please let me know if you know something helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you set `after-init-hook` (in fact, you do so twice: once in the `use-package` form and once after it.  This has the effect of setting whatever the initial buffer is to `org-roam-mode` which is almost certainly not what you want.

Remove those bits and you end up with something that works:

```lisp
(use-package org-roam
      :ensure t
      :custom
      (org-roam-directory "/$HOME/Zettelkasten")
      :bind (:map org-roam-mode-map
              (("C-c n l" . org-roam)
               ("C-c n f" . org-roam-find-file)
               ("C-c n r" . org-roam-graph))
              :map org-mode-map
              (("C-c n i" . org-roam-insert))
              (("C-c n I" . org-roam-insert-immediate))))
```

Comment: Sorry I may have to edit my post/ original question to better reflect the situation. It was not the `after-init-hook` that is the real problem. The real problem is `M-x org-roam` doesn't work! I realized it only a little while ago. (I have commented about it above as well). I just opened [a github issue on org-roam](https://github.com/org-roam/org-roam/issues/2267) based on our earlier discussions and what I now know.

Comment: I suggest you open a new question about this and leave the current one as is.

Comment: Well, true... I also feel your answer solves my original question - it will stop the scratch buffer from dominating other buffers when opening files. I also understand why using `after-init-hook` may not be good practice. It will always set every buffer to org-roam mode and that is not the correct thing to do. So I will accept your answer for this question.

Comment: For anyone else struggling with `org-roam` version 2.2.2, please note: really `after-init-hook` is not the heart of the problem. I have already started a github issue [here](https://github.com/org-roam/org-roam/issues/2267). So I am not going to make a new emacs.stackexchange post on this same issue. Please proceed over to the github issue.

Comment: If I were you, I would prepare a minimal init file (just the `use-package` perhaps) and then start emacs with `emacs -q -l /path/to/minimal-init.el`, bypassing your init file altogether. It is likely that the `org-roam` people will ask you to do exactly that if they cannot reproduce the problem, so you might as well try it.